# Как мне удалить первый символ из инпута чтобы не удалились остальные?

Tags: reactjs, input

У меня лимит 10000 и я хочу увеличить его до 20000. Я хочу убрать одну цифру. Но когда я её убираю сумма сбрасывает до 0 и приходится приходится писать заново.
Нужно сделать чтобы если я убираю первую цифру в начале, то сумма не обнуляется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компонент с инпутом:

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          hided: false,
          minLim: this.props.minLim,
          maxLim: this.props.maxLim,
        };
      }

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (this.props.minLim !== prevProps.minLim) this.setState({minLim: this.props.minLim});
    if (this.props.maxLim !== prevProps.maxLim) this.setState({maxLim: this.props.maxLim});
  }

      <input
        autoComplete="off"
        className="classic_input limit_changer_input"
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        ref={ref => this.ref = ref}
        name="currentMinLimChange"
        onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e, this.ref)}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder || ''}
        value={parseInt(minLim)}
      />
```

В пропсах в onChange приходит метод changeLim

```
changeLim = (e): void => {
    const {target} = e;
    let pos = target.selectionStart;
    let value = target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    if (parseFloat(value) < 1 || !value) {
      value = '0';
      pos = 1;
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    this.setState({[target.name]: value}, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.prepareSettlementRate();
        target.selectionStart = pos;
        target.selectionEnd = pos;
      }, 0.000001);
    });
  }

  sendLims = (): void => {
    const {currentMinLimChange, currentMaxLimChange} = this.state;
    const {offer, t} = this.props;
    this.setState({loadingSendLims: true});
    const prevMinLim = offer.minAmount;
    const prevMaxLim = offer.maxAmount;
    const newMinLim = parseFloat(String(currentMinLimChange));
    const newMaxLim = parseFloat(String(currentMaxLimChange));
    const sendObj: Record<string, number | string | boolean> = {};
    if (prevMinLim !== newMinLim && newMinLim) sendObj.minAmount = newMinLim;
    else sendObj.minAmount = prevMinLim;
    if (prevMaxLim !== newMaxLim && newMaxLim) sendObj.maxAmount = newMaxLim;
    else sendObj.maxAmount = prevMaxLim;

    if (sendObj.maxAmount <= sendObj.minAmount) {
      this.setState({
        currentMinLimChange: null,
        currentMaxLimChange: null,
        messageTextLims: t('oneOffer.limitsValidationErrorMessage'),
      }, () => {
        setTimeout(() => {this.setState({messageTextLims: ''});}, 2400);
      });
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

может попробовать `ChangeLim` поменять на такую

```
changeLim = (e): void => {
    const {target} = e;
    let pos = target.selectionStart;
    let value = target.value;
    // @ts-ignore
    this.setState({[target.name]: value}, () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.prepareSettlementRate();
        target.selectionStart = pos;
        target.selectionEnd = pos;
      }, 0.000001);
    });
  }
```

Comment: все тоже самое, не помогло..